# Как запустить smooth-scrollbar?

Tags: javascript

Смотрю [сюда](https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/) и пытаюсь включить smooth-scrollbar.
Вроде делаю всё по документации, но ничего не работает

```js
const mainNode = document.querySelector('#main');

Scrollbar.init(mainNode);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 50vh;
}

section:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smooth-scrollbar/8.7.4/smooth-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

<main class="main" id="main" data-scrollbar>

  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо ограничивать высоту прокручиваемого блока, чтобы контент из него "вываливался"

```js
const mainNode = document.querySelector('#main');

Scrollbar.init(mainNode);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 50vh;
}

section:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: black;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smooth-scrollbar/8.7.4/smooth-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

<main class="main" id="main" data-scrollbar>

  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>

</main>
```